# how to install java 3d 1.5.2 in ubuntu for vm ware work station

Tags: java

I have installed latest version of ubuntu on vm ware work station .
 can any one tell easiest way to install java and java3d in it?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install libjava3d-java` from ubuntu terminal?

Comment: Yes but it is telling unable to find required packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and install the Java 3D API:

```
sudo apt-get install libjava3d-java
```

And install Java 7 (OpenJDK) with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Or Oracle 8 Java with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```